# Should I order GraphQL results server side or client side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

We are using graphql-ruby in one of our internal projects: A Rails API backend serving a React Native Web frontend. I'm curious as to what is considered best practice in regard to handling ordering of returned results.

One option I see is that we provide both `order_direction` and `field_to_order_by` arguments, and the client must explicitly state each for the query (providing defaults as well, of course).

One way to handle this would be

```rb
if (sort_column = args[:sort_by])
  if (direction = args[:direction])
    users = users.order(sort_column.to_sym => direction.to_sym)
  else
    users = users.order(sort_column.to_sym) # default sort order
  end
end
```

Another option of course would be to provide all results in a pre-defined direction (`ASC` or `DESC`) and have the client itself reorder. This seems very inefficient, however. As there's a real dearth of information on how to approach this, I'm curious what's considered best practice.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Ordering on the database level will always be quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best practice ordering results should be made as far down the server as possible (database).

But, as I understand you're questioning between ordering results on the server side (GraphQL API) or on the frontend side (React Native Application), so:

I would recommend providing the client application with an option to get the results in a specific order and handle the sorting on the Server API, that way the client application should only display the results without the need of spending time processing them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marco! I think you're right that that makes the most sense and with the highest level of efficiency.

Comment: Sure @ianbayne, don't forget to accept the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @Marco, I'm not super familiar with Stackoverflow yet.

Comment: No worries, we're here to help :) here is a guide that can help you for the future https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers